# How to make Xlib print error message, but not exit?

Tags: error-handling, xlib

"The action of the default handlers is to print an explanatory message and exit." [(link)](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/default-handlers.html)

Example of such message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  12 (X_ConfigureWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0xc0007a
  Serial number of failed request:  140
  Current serial number in output stream:  141
```

If I set (XSetErrorHandler) my own "ignore everything" error handler, the "explanatory messages" disappear.

How to make Xlib ignore errors, but still print error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to format your own message. The contents of the message is the contents of the XErrorEvent struct:

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/default-handlers.html

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want those error messages you pretty much have two options:

- Pull `_XPrintDefaultError` out of `XlibInt.c` along with some private headers (with all the caveats of using library-private definitions).
- Redefine `exit()` not to actually exit when `_XDefautError` calls it.

Neither is especially pretty and both may break and reduce your portability, but they do work.